# solving PDE equation like Helmholtz equation in 2D

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

In my project I need to solve following equation analytically  could anyone help me ? As I read the other questions, my equation seems like   Helmholtz equation
$$
     \triangledown^2 u(x,y) - k_cu(x,y) =0 \quad x,y \in \Omega \\
       u(x,L) = u(x,0),
       u(0,y) = 1
    \quad x \in [0,L] , y \in [0,L]  $$

here is my code in Mathematica

```
Dc = 1460
Kc = 9.41/(10^2)
 LaplacEquation =  Dc*D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] + Dc* D[u[x, y], {y, 2}] - Kc*u[x, y] == 0
  DSolve[LaplacEquation, {u[x, y], u[x, y]}, {x, y}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Just to clarify, you wish to solve this with the computer algebra software *Mathematica*? Have you tried `DSolve[]`? -- OTOH, if it is just a mathematics question, the site math.stackexchange.com is more appropriate.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thank you for your answer.  Yes I want to solve it using Mathematica. I also tried DSolve[] but because non principal part $k_cu(x,y)$ DSolve[] could not find the answer

Comment: Could you post the code for what you tried?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I have edited my post and added my code

Answer (score 3):

This is a solution to the problem with exactly the boundary conditions as stated:

```
Dc = 1460
Kc = 9.41/(10^2)
LaplacEquation = 
 Dc*D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] + Dc*D[u[x, y], {y, 2}] - Kc*u[x, y] == 0

v[x] /. 
 First[DSolve[{LaplacEquation /. u -> (v[#] &), v[0] == 1}, v[x], x]]

(* ==> E^(-0.0080282 x) (1. - 1. C[1] + E^(0.0160564 x) C[1]) *)
```

All I did here is observe that the boundary conditions can be satisfied if the solution has no dependence on `y` whatsoever. I then inserted that assumption into the `Laplacian` in the form of a replacement `u -> (v[#]&)` which states that the new function `v` depends only on `x`.

Answer (score 2):

`DSolve` has limited abilities with PDEs. I can get part way there, maybe, but something is fishy about the result *Mathematica* returns.

First, since your equation is linear and homogeneous and has a simple relationship among the coefficients, we can rewrite it as a BVP over a unit square:
$$\nabla^2u + a\, u=0, u(x,0)=u(x,1),\ u(0,y)=1$$
It is apparently still too general for `DSolve` to handle, but if we impose further boundary constraints, namely,
$$u(x,0)=u(x,1)=u(0,y)=u(1,y)=1\,,$$
we can get a solution for various values of `a`, similar to the Helmholtz example in the docs for [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html).  Luckily, the dependence on `a` is "obvious," and we can get an expression in terms of `a`:

```
pde = a * u[x, y] + Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0;
bcs = {u[x, 0] == 1, u[x, 1] == 1, u[0, y] == 1, u[1, y] == 1};
Block[{a = 5},
  {dsol0} = DSolve[{pde, bcs}, u, {x, y}]
  ];
dsol = dsol0 /. {5 -> a, -5 -> -a};
u[x, y] /. dsol // TraditionalForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you doubt it, you can try other values of `a`:

```
Block[{a = 167},
  DSolve[{pde, bcs}, u[x, y], {x, y}]
  ] // TraditionalForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are a couple of problems.  Numerically this is hard to evaluate, so checking it is difficult.  And it does not look symmetric in `x` and `y`, even though the problem is.  (Maybe someone will recognize this as a common sum, but for me, it would take more time than I can give at the moment. It's not a sum *Mathematica* can do.)

This is the best I can do.
My reformulation has more restrictive boundary conditions than the OP's, and in my mind there is some doubt whether the solution is correct.  But maybe it will help the OP.